# ffmpeg command, what is the "best" config to re-encode video Youtube?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, youtube, matplotlib

Let's say we have a video generated with `matplotlib.animation` with the code below (while can't figure how  to have the mp4 file with HD 1080p, but we can re-encode with Final cut pro HD 1080p)

```
Writer = animation.writers['ffmpeg']#code to save the example.mp4
writer = Writer(fps=0.9, codec="h264", bitrate=1000000, metadata=dict(artist='me'))
animator.save('example.mp4', writer=writer)
```

When this mp4 file is imported into Final Cut, we have the option to make it HD 1080p.

*Q: How can "convert" an mp4 file with HD 1080P as planned for youtube use with ffmpeg command?*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gndcF.png)

Comment: Have you checked questions with "ffmpeg encode youtube"? Should provide many hits.

Comment: You conform the file to your project as you import it to FCP, then at Export there's an 'Export to YouTube' button. It will even sign in & upload it for you.

Comment: @Tetsujin, try not to use FCP. The question is how to do the best config for a youtube videos with FFmpeg?

Comment: Then why mention FCP at all if it has nothing to do with your workflow or question?

Comment: when video is generated with matplotlib.animation with the config above, it is not the best for youtube, but it cloud be re-encode with my desired confige (when It was imported into FCP)  I mentioned FCP to show that the video is possible to en-code with HD quality.